# Flutter change color of text return by form validator

Tags: flutter

I have a `TextFormField` which has a validator which returns a string. I want to show the validation error message in red color and may be some other styling

- How can i change its color?
- Can i configure it in Theme so that i can configure it once for all forms in my app?

  TextFormField(

```js
TextFormField(
  textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
    filled: true,
    icon: Icon(Icons.person),
    hintText: 'First name',
    labelText: 'First Name *',
  ),
  onSaved: (String value) {
    this._customer.fName = value;
  },
  validator: _validateName,
  initialValue: this._customer.fName,
),
```

Edit1:

I added following to ThemeData.

```
final ThemeData myTheme = ThemeData(

 errorStyle: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.red,
      fontSize: null,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
  errorColor: Color(0xffd32f2f),
)
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Lead Manager',
      theme: myTheme,
      home: Home(),
    );

  }
}
```

But it doesnot work.

Answer (score 15):

You could style the errorText like this.

```
TextFormField(
      textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
          filled: true,
          icon: Icon(Icons.person),
          hintText: 'First name',
          labelText: 'First Name *',
          //textError styling
          errorStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.teal)),
      onSaved: (String value) {
        this._customer.fName = value;
      },
      validator: _validateName,
      initialValue: this._customer.fName,
    );
```

more details here [errorStyle property](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration/errorStyle.html).

Comment: that worked. But i want to do it globally once so that i dont have to repeat it everywhere.

Comment: You simply could create a custom TextFieldForm to use it evreywhere instead of the basic `TextFormField`, then you could style it however you want and only do it once.
Because i dont think you can change the style from the theme, probably just color.

Comment: errorStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.teal)), helped me. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

To change the error color of your `TextFields` and other posible error messages for your whole application, in your `MaterialApp` declaration add the theme property and override the `errorColor`:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: Home(),
      // Add this line
      theme: ThemeData(errorColor: Colors.yellow),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The edit you posted is not using my answer, you are overriding both the errorColor and the errorStyle. Have you tried just overriding the errorColor? Are you sure you aren't overriding this somewhere else, locally, on your app? This is a very basic change to the root of your MaterialApp.

Comment: The edit is doing the same work as u described. But its first creating an object and then referring to it. I am sure that am not overriding it anywhere else.

Comment: You are defining both the errorColor and the errorStyle. The documention isn't very clear, but there is a chance that one is overriding the other. Have you tried defining only the errorColor?